# mySQL master-master replication

Tags: mysql-replication, mysql-cluster

I have a 3 server mySQL/PHP/Apache cluster (each on different continents for maximum resilience). I have read a lot of advice which all says - don't do this!

Essentially the reasons I want to do this is:

1. Resilience - 2 of 3 servers could go down and the users can still log in and see their data/ do their work
2. Backup - kind of as above
3. Load share - I can distribute the front-end load AND back-end server processes across the different boxes

I have looked at different options including percona galera, all seem to have drawbacks. The main being transparency - at some point a link or server will go down, then you get vague BINLOG errors, then its all a massive problem...

So I have implemented this myself instead - I have a set of scripts that build INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers on each table - any changes are logged in a replication table. An every minute process pushes these changes to the other 2 servers. I also have processes which check the CHECKSUM and alert on any discrepancies.

Its works great. Not easy I grant you! Multiple fiddly things, including:

- not using float column type (0.3434 does not equal 0.3434...)
- avoiding auto-increment keys (if data is inserted on 2 different servers at the same minute, they could both take the next value, then the reciprocal inserts will fail).
- remember to re-run that create triggers script if you change a table structure

So, my question is... What could go wrong? Where/why is this going to go fail? What don't I know??

Comment: Get yourself a copy of "Designing Data-Intensive Applications" by Martin Kleppmann. I think it has a detailed description of the CAP theorem with pictures.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you are asking us to appraise a design and implementation without enough detail. Providing that detail goes WAY beyond the scope of a stackoverflow Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

On the contrary to the above, i think this is an excellent question. They are not asking for an analysis of what they have done, just the general "4th window" of what are the unknown unknowns.

Data intensive applications is an [excellent book](https://github.com/ms2ag16/Books/blob/master/Designing%20Data-Intensive%20Applications%20-%20Martin%20Kleppmann.pdf)
They call it Multi-leader replication rather than master-master and has a good discussion of why this has pitfalls. As as you have seen, services with Galera and Percona don't do it -- so there must be a good reason (I have not played with Blackhole yet).

I think the key message is that you need to ensure the table structure can cope with multi-lead replication - so if 2 new entries are added on separate servers, you wouldn't (as you say) want to have an auto-increment key field - you need to have designed the table and application to use maybe user id and timestamp etc... (so thats a manual work pain).

You also probably need decent tools to be able to quickly compare and tables across databases and spot inconsistencies.